# How do I get Sql Server Bids 2008 to not re-run a query when only updating the format of an SSRS report?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, report-designer

For several weeks my colleagues and I have been trying to keep BIDS from running a separate query when switching from Design view to Preview after only modifying a Sql Server Reporting Services report layout. Is that a bug or a feature or are we likely doing something wrong?

Comment: This was specific to 2008 R2 and there is a bug. The fix is at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2282505

Answer (score 0):

If you run the report with identical parameters, then this should not happen.

Each time you run a report, you should see a .rdl.DATA file appear in the same folder as the RDL file that you are running, this contains cached data

Comment: It is not generating the .rdl.DATA files...not sure why that would be any ideas?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found that is was actualy a bug in 2008 R2. Which I didn't specify.

Comment: It's worth googing for " <your issue> ssrs site:connect.microsoft.com " on occasion. You will often find workarounds and updates for any issues that the community is experiencing.